# Live Agent Pre Chat API - Matching Leads

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, chat

I have Live Agent up with the pre-chat APIs coded in the pre-chat form, as per the developer guide. I am attempting to find a lead or contact based on email provided in the pre-chat form. Here are the lines with the Live Agent Pre-Chat APIs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Lead" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName;Email,ContactEmail;Company,ContactEmail;LeadSource,LeadSource"/>

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName;Email,ContactEmail;LeadSource,LeadSource" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Lead" value="Email,true;IsConverted,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Lead" value="Email,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Lead" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true;Phone,true;Company,true;LeadSource,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Lead" value="true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Lead" value="LeadId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="ContactId" />
```

It's almost working as intended, but the **doFind method for the lead is  including converted leads**. So, when an email address for a converted lead is inputted to the form, the console displays both the contact AND converted lead.

My thought was to try and add IsConverted as part of the search:

```
<input type="hidden" name='liveagent.prechat:IsConverted' id='isconverted' value=''/> 

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Lead" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName;Email,ContactEmail;Company,ContactEmail;LeadSource,LeadSource;IsConverted,IsConverted"/>

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Lead" value="Email,true;IsConverted,true" />
```

But attempting to pass a blank value doesn't work.

Any thoughts here on how I might keep the converted leads from coming up?

Comment: Did you try giving isConverted value false before passing to doFind method?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Guess I'm not sure how to pass a boolean through this API... You can see that I'm trying to pass IsConverted as ''

`<input type="hidden" name='liveagent.prechat:IsConverted' id='isconverted' value=''/> `

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix - and it was right in the documentation:

`'

it's the **false**. I thought that was the first thing I tried, but apparently not...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: To clarify, I'm pretty sure @Danomyte66 is saying that for the hidden liveagent.prechat:IsConverted field, instead of using '' as the value it is correct to use 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've tweaked your code a bit. I think it works just fine.

You only needed to add IsConverted to ExactMatch line. It should look like this;

```
<input type="hidden" name='liveagent.prechat:IsConverted' id='isconverted' value=''/> 

    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Lead" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName;Email,ContactEmail;Company,ContactEmail;LeadSource,LeadSource"/>

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,LeadFirstName;LastName,LeadLastName;Email,LeadEmail" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Lead" value="Email,true;IsConverted,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Lead" value="Email,true;IsConverted,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Lead" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true;Phone,true;Company,true;LeadSource,true" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Lead" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had that in my code - didn't show it on my post. It's still not working. Now, when the chat is being requested, the live agent chat detail show IsConverted as coming in blank...

Comment: So do you have two lines of isExactMatch:Lead or you posted earlier version of your page? I'm at lost on this moment. I'm posting my pre chat survey page a bit more. It works (Does not show converted lead, only contact)

Comment: I did have this line: `<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Lead" value="Email,true;IsConverted,true" />'